# GDB: breakpoint in linux built-in module fails

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, gdb

I am debugging linux kernel using two virtual machines connected via serial port.

**Target machine** awaits connection from remote gdb, by inserting `kgdbwait()` and `kgdboc=ttyS0,115200` in the correct entry in  `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

In **Host machine**

```
sudo gdb ./vmlinux
```

Symbols are read and I am supposed to be able to put breakpoints on function names.

```
(gdb) break oom_kill_process
Breakpoint 1 at 0xc1172ef0: file mm/oom_kill.c, line 843.
```

Works fine!

However, if I set a breakpoint at `htb_dequeue_tree` which is found [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/net/sched/sch_htb.c#L844), I get the following error:

```
(gdb) break htb_dequeue_tree
```

> No symbol "htb_dequeue_tree" in current context.

Comment: this function may be inlined. Try to set a break on a concrete address (b *0x12345678)

Comment: @AlexHoppus I tried `break net/sched/sch_htb.c:htb_dequeue_tree` and it didn't work. When I did this for `mm/oom_kill.c:oom_kill_process` it succeeded so for some reason `sch_htb.c` is not recognized? anyway, thanks for your comment, but how do I find that address of the function?

Comment: use objdump vmlinux . I didn't get how what you are saying refutes my assumption about inlined function.

Comment: @AlexHoppus didn't mean to refute your suggestion, I wanted to add that `sch_htb.c` is not found. I am getting `No source file named net/sched/sch_htb.c`

Comment: if you can rebuild the kernel  use __attribute__((optimize("O0"))) and __attribute__ ((noinline))

Comment: @AlexHoppus I've solved this in menuconfig by making the module a built-in part and not inserted dynamically. By changing the `<m>` to `<*>` then remaking the kernel and installing the modules... in the new created vmlinux the symbols are presented and a breakpoint is inserted at the desired function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that [HTB](http://luxik.cdi.cz/~devik/qos/htb/manual/userg.htm) is a built-in module which is dynamically inserted, hence when making, it is not included in the `vmlinux` file which contains the symbols.

To fix this, it has to be changed to an internal part and not a module, and this can be done in `menuconfig`

Just run

```
make menuconfig
```

Find the module, and change it from `<m>` to `<*>`

Remake your kernel, install modules and install, this should result in a new `vmlinux` which will contain the symbols of the desired module so you will be able to breakpoint at any line\function name.

Answer (score 0):

The most typical cause is the function getting inlined - then there is no symbol to begin with. Quite often you can put a break on a file+line pair (e.g. foo.c:42).

In your particular case the function is static and has only one user: htp_dequeue. If you disassemble it you will probably see the code from htp_dequeue_tree slurped in. If not, there is some other breakage going on(does breaking on other functions work?)

Comment: All I am getting is No source file named `net/sched/sch_htb.c`

Comment: It ended up being a different thing. Thanks for your help though.